# vb.net - how to stream write file to file

Tags: vb.net, file, stream

I need a way to stream write from one file to the other in vb.net so that the entire files don`t have to be loaded in memory.  Here is what I want: Stream read bytes in file 1 ---> stream write append bytes to file 2.

I will be working with large files, multiple GB, so  I need the most effiant way of doing it, and don`t want to load all content of the file to memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example of reading and writing the files in "chunks" using a byte array buffer.  You can decide how big to make the buffer:

```
    Dim bytesRead As Integer
    Dim buffer(4096) As Byte
    Using inFile As New System.IO.FileStream("c:\some path\folder\file1.ext", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
        Using outFile As New System.IO.FileStream("c:\some path\folder\file2.ext", IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
            Do
                bytesRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                If bytesRead > 0 Then
                    outFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                End If
            Loop While bytesRead > 0
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: The max amount read will be the size of the buffer.  Or do you mean you only want to copy a portion of the file and then stop?

Comment: Gotcha...see your other question.